# terraform error: unsupported argument in module in tf plan

Tags: amazon-web-services, syntax-error, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-modules

I am getting the Error: Unsupported argument, when I run terraform plan in version 12.24.

```
Error: Unsupported argument

  on .terraform/modules/admin_portal.cf_portal/modules/aws-terraform-cloudfront_s3_origin/main.tf line 60, in resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "cf_distribution":
  60:   logging_config = local.bucket_logging[local.bucket_logging_config]

An argument named "logging_config" is not expected here. Did you mean to
define a block of type "logging_config"?
```

Code in tf file:

```
  logging_config = local.bucket_logging[local.bucket_logging_config]
```

how do I fix it?

Comment: Can you show full code where `logging_config` occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
variable "logging" {
  default = local.bucket_logging[local.bucket_logging_config]
}
```

After that you can use that with var.logging on any statement

But I recommend you use the local. when you need inside the statements and not to put in a var.